# Extracting String's from a String JAVA

Tags: java, string, parsing

Hello I want to extract "Hello, World!" "and" and the Paragraph "This is a minimal....." from the given string in JAVA. I am having problems in extracting, so can anyone help me with it?

So I always get different Strings and want to extract the string between 2 square brackets []......[].

```
String s1="[sh1] Hello, World! [/s11] and [pp]This is a minimal "hello world" HTML document. It demonstrates the basic structure of an HTML file and anchors. [/xy]"
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code you would like to share?

Comment: I am getting all the HTML source using GET Request and want to remover tags from the string and then I only want to print whatever is there in the body i.e. string in between tags. So I separated the Body content using String s1=s.substring(s.indexOf("<body>")+6,s.indexOf("</body>")); Now I further more want to remove all tags and just print the String in between them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Pattern & Matcher to match square brackets:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[[^\\]]*\\]([^\\]]*)\\[[^\\]]*\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println( "Found value: " + matcher.group(1).trim() );
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/kNKBgg

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it is giving 2 errors                                    Clientonly.java:82: error: illegal escape character Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("](.*?)["); ^ Clientonly.java:82: error: illegal escape character Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("](.*?)["); ^

Comment: Thanks for the help Nagarjun but they ain't working.  In the question actually I want String between <>.... <> 2 square brackets but while typing question when I put <> it takes it to be a HTML code and hence does not print <> and that is why I had to print [].

Comment: I am getting all the HTML source using GET Request and want to remover tags from the string and then I only want to print whatever is there in the body i.e. string in between tags. So I separated the Body content using String s1=s.substring(s.indexOf("<body>")+6,s.indexOf("</body>")); Now I further more want to remove all tags and just print the String in between them.

Comment: @Arnav As Ana mentioned in below answer, you should use DOM or SAX parser if you are parsing HTML document. My solution can be modified for matching HTML as well but it is not recommended way.

Comment: Hi Nagarjun, can you help me with     /\<body[^>]*\>([^]*)\<\/body/    Pattern and Matcher? it gives an error when I try to put in Pattern.compile("/\<body[^>]*\>([^]*)\<\/body/")

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use RegEx-es to do this (it's what Pattern and Matcher do) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la) for reason why you shouldn't. While you could use this for the particular bracket example, if you expect full-blown HTML don't do it.

If you want to extract content from HTML use a parser, for example SAXParser or DOMParser - see [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK3000) for examples.

Comment: Thanks. that correct. However my answer was for matching square brackets like BBCode in a string  as op's description meant like it.

Comment: Thanks Ana and Nagarjun. Appreciate it.